# basvandenberg/ng-select issue with simple string array

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-ngselect

I'm using the following ng-select module and I am having issues using it with simple arrays.

https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select

The option format it expects is an array of objects:

```
{
   value: string;
   label: string;
}
```

But I don't have that option with the data being provided.

My object:

```
{
    name: "something",
    tags: ["option1","option2","option3"],
    tagPrimary: "",
    ...
}
```

In my Angular5 component template:

```
<ng-select
      placeholder="Select a primary option..."
      [(ngModel)]="obj.tagPrimary"
      [options]="obj.tags">
</ng-select>
```

Now when using this, the dropdown that is generate has the 3 options but doesn't display anything because it is looking for an object with a label key.

I tried to create a function that would format the data correctly.

```
function format(tags){
    arr=[];
    _.each(tags,function(tag){
        obj.push({label: tag, value: tag});
    }
    return obj;
}

<ng-select
          placeholder="Select a primary option..."
          [(ngModel)]="obj.tagPrimary"
          [options]="format(obj.tags)">
</ng-select>
```

Although it does render the dropdown correctly now, the items are un-selectable. When viewing the source the DOM inspector, it appears that the style attribute on each option will disappear/reappear (like it is re-initializing with the function being triggered over and over again.)

is the function created correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning `[options]="format(obj.tags)"` directly in your template, which likely causes the method to trigger on each change detection cycle, you should assign the return value of `format()` method to another 'property' in your component and use that property in the template.

Assuming you have your `obj` available in the `ngOnInit()` (otherwise you should make this assignment when your `obj` property is available with values within your component),

In your component,

```
optionsForSelect: { label: string; value: string; }[]; // specifying the type, not necessary though, a type of 'any[]' would be sufficient

format(tags){
  arr=[];
  _.each(tags,function(tag){
      arr.push({label: tag, value: tag});
  }
  return arr;
}

ngOnInit() {
  //after you get 'obj' property
  this.optionsForSelect = this.format(this.obj.tags);
}
```

In your template,

```
<ng-select
    placeholder="Select a primary option..."
    [(ngModel)]="obj.tagPrimary"
    [options]="optionsForSelect">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the direction I needed.